# How to change auto-complete behaviour in vim?

Tags: vim

Explain by example.

I want to split my window and open *file-x.txt*

In the folder where I am working I also have the set of files: from *file-a.txt* to *file-z.txt*

If I type:

`:sp file`<kbd>Tab</kbd>

Instead of getting 
`:sp file-`  As I usually get in bash.

I get:
`:sp file-a.txt`

This is not very convenient as I need to either tap <kbd>Tab</kbd> ridiculous times or type really long names.

Is there a way to set the auto-complete behaviour for VIM for file names?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `'wildmode'` setting controls the completion in the command line. Try

```
:set wildmode=longest:full,full
```

This should achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard here:

```
:sp *x<Tab>
```

In the scenario you describe, hitting a single `<Tab>` should complete the command-line to:

:sp file-x.txt

Comment: `?`, `*` et al are not regular expressions, they are file wildcards (also known as globs in shells). Vim mostly refers to them as _file-pattern_.

Comment: “wildcard” [means](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wildcard) “a *character* that takes the place of …”, thus `*x` can’t be a wildcard. It is usually referred by “[glob] pattern” in shells (“glob” itself [is a technique](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/glob)) or “file pattern” in vim manual. Though I have sometimes seen glob patterns referred to as just “globs” I’ve never seen somebody using term “wildcard” to refer to some pattern. You can read bash or zsh manual to be sure that definition from wiktionary is true and “glob” is not used as “pattern”.

Comment: I was refering to `*`, not `*x`.